# cross join with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using a cross join to duplicate rows outputted from my database.

I would like a filter so that only certain values are duplicated

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName From Employee 
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT TOP 2 Number FROM Numbers) Numbers
WHERE EmployeeID in (20,30)
```

This outputs as

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeForeName
20          Jamie
30          Karl
20          Jamie
30          Karl
```

How would I do this but only duplicate where EmployeeID = 20; Resulting in the following

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeForeName
20          Jamie
30          Karl
20          Jamie
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you showed us what Employee and Numbers look like

Comment: Have u tried : `WHERE EmployeeID  = 20` ?

Comment: The easiest way is to write two queries and use a `union all` to combine the results. One query without the cross join looks for `<> 20` and the other one with the cross join that looks for `= 20`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.EmployeeForeName 
FROM Employee AS e
CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT t.n
    FROM (VALUES (1), (2)) AS t(n)
    WHERE (t.n = 1) OR (e.EmployeeID = 20)) AS x
WHERE e.EmployeeID in (20,30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to want a `cross join` on both values.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName
FROM Employee CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 2 Number FROM Numbers) Numbers
WHERE EmployeeID IN (20)
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeID IN (30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want only EmployeeId 20 to be duplicated but not 30, I dont know what is in the Numbers table, I would do like below

```
DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE 
(
    EmployeeID INT, EmployeeForeName VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TBL
SELECT 20 EmployeeID,'Jamie' EmployeeForeName
UNION ALL
SELECT 20,'Jamie'
UNION ALL
SELECT 30,'Karl'
UNION ALL
SELECT 30,'Karl'

select * from @TBL where EmployeeID =20
union all
select distinct * from @TBL where EmployeeID =30
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName From Employee 
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT TOP 2 Number FROM Numbers) Numbers
WHERE EmployeeID =20
union all
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName
FROM Employee
WHERE EmployeeID =30
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should do the trick;

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName From Employee 
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT TOP 2 Number FROM Numbers) Numbers
WHERE EmployeeID = 20
UNION ALL 
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeForeName From Employee 
WHERE EmployeeID  = 30
```